# SharePoint Workflow Auto CC

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I have created workflows in SharePoint to send emails to end users giving information and asking questions.  However, when the EU replies, if they do not push reply all it goes to a rarely monitored mailbox and gets lost.
Is there a way that I can make the cc line I already built into the workflow automatically cc those people regardless of if the EU pushes reply or reply all?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this. It is a training issue.  You might want to alter your communications to include a standard paragraph at the end reminding users to use the Reply All option when replying otherwise their email will arrive at an unmonitored mailbox.